# Displaying UWP project in Design mode without Anniversary edition

Tags: visual-studio, uwp

I wonder if it's possible to display XAML (in Design mode) in UWP without the Anniversary Edition. I have the 2017 RC edition but at my university the computers haven't been upgraded to the Anniversary edition. This means that all my code runs fine, but I can't display it in Design mode in Visual Studio.

Is there a setting (say in Properties or so) that fixes this? I guess that a solution would be to target an older version but I don't know if this is so, or how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the **Target Version** in **Properties** to the OS Build of your system to enable Design mode.
[image]

For example, if you are using a computer with November Update (Version 1511, OS Build 10586), then you can change **Target Version** to `Windows 10 (10.0; Build 10586)`. Besides, you also need to make sure you have installed the corresponding [Windows 10 SDK (10586)](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive) on your computer. After this you can reopen your project, the Design View should be able to work now.

However, please note that after downgrading the Target Version from `Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (10.0; Build 14393)`, the app will can't use [new features  introduced in Anniversary Update](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/whats-new/windows-10-version-1607). The Design View might still not work if you've used new features in your app.

Comment: thank you so much for your detailed reply! Excactly svar I needed.